# Chaining function that returns promise doesn't resolve after flushing timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

The chain inside this testcode will not resolve... It resolve level 1 and level2.

```
    it('Three level promise', inject(function ($q, $timeout, $rootScope) {
        var plusOne = function(value) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve(value+1);
            }, 10);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        var promiseCall = function() {
            return plusOne(1).then(function (data){
                console.error('call1 resolved', data);
                return plusOne(data).then(function (data2){
                    console.error('call2 resolved', data2);
                    return plusOne(data2).then(function (data3){
                        console.error('call3 resolved', data3);
                            return data3;
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        var result;

        promiseCall().then(function (data) {
            result = data;
        });

        $timeout.flush(); // Force timeout to be flushed.

        expect(result).toBe(3);
    }));
```

I cant see why this shouldnt work... :-(

... And stackoverflow dont like that I have so much code inside this request.

Comment: So you never get `call3 resolved` log or test fails?

Comment: Why are you using `console.error` in a success handler (instead of `console.log`)?

Comment: As it stands, expect `result` to be `undefined`. Move the `expect()` inside `promiseCall().then(function(){...})` and expect `data` to be `NaN` (`undefined + 1`). Then return `data` and `data2` from their repective functions and expect `data` to be `4` (1+1+1+1).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

`$timeout.flush();` flushes the first `$timeout` call. The other two haven't been called at this point. So you would have to call `$timeout.flush();` three times, not just once.

Second: The expected result is not 3, but 4. You start with 1 and the resolved value is always +1. You resolve three times.